# download datatable as a csv file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

Hi all I am trying to allow the user to download data from a database so they can manipulate it with out having access to the database. so far I have this it makes the file but I need it to download to the client pc. Any tips?

```
Protected Sub ExportDataTableToCSV(cmdText As String)
    Try
        Dim sqlcon_Local As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        sqlcon_Local.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Portal").ConnectionString
        Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlcon_Local)
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(objCmd)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim filename As String = Server.MapPath("~/download.csv")
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filename, False)

        Dim iColCount As Integer = dt.Columns.Count
        For i As Integer = 0 To iColCount - 1
            sw.Write(dt.Columns(i))
            If i < iColCount - 1 Then
                sw.Write(",")
            End If
        Next
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine)

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            For i As Integer = 0 To iColCount - 1
                If Not Convert.IsDBNull(dr(i)) Then
                    sw.Write(dr(i).ToString())
                End If
                If i < iColCount - 1 Then
                    sw.Write(",")
                End If
            Next
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine)
        Next
        sw.Close()

        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/csv"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.csv")
        Response.WriteFile(filename)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

what am I doing wrong?
any input will be welcome.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

please change  Response.ContentType as

Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
   Public Shared Function Export_CSV(ByVal cmdText As String) As String

        Dim message As String = Nothing

        Try

            Dim sqlcon_Local As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            sqlcon_Local.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Portal").ConnectionString
            Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlcon_Local)
            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(objCmd)
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)

            Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
            context.Response.Clear()

            For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                context.Response.Write(column.ColumnName + ",")
            Next

            context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)

            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    context.Response.Write(row(i).ToString.Replace(",", String.Empty) + ",")
                Next

                context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)

            Next

            context.Response.ContentType = "txt/csv"
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + download + ".csv")

            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

            message = "Export Successful"

        Catch ex As Exception

            message = ex.Message.ToString

        End Try

        Return message

    End Function
```

ref : http://www.thewebbureau.com/tech_blog/post/Export-DataTable-To-CSV.aspx

If you have problem with IE browser

change

```
 context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + download + ".csv")
```

to

```
 context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; inline=" + download + ".csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, it doesn't seem to download the file. it creates a exception at "context.Response.End()"

Comment: @Ja77aman remove `context.Response.End()` and  add `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`

Comment: OK thanks for that, the exception is gone, but still no download. should not the browser start to download after the CompleteRequest() call?

Comment: @Ja77aman which browser are you testing? please check my updated answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28077/discussion-between-damith-and-ja77aman)